# Palette color in android

Tags: android, color-palette

I am new to android ,I am display recyclerview with image ,all images save in drawable folder its working fine but i need palette color to my textview ,i don't know how to achive this any one please help me how to get this , all image from local

here my class

PrimaryFrragment.Class

```
public class PrimaryFragment extends Fragment {



private SimpleCardViewAdapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

public PrimaryFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootview= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_primary, container, false);



    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)rootview. findViewById(R.id.list);
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new BaseItemAnimator() {
        @Override
        protected void animateRemoveImpl(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {

        }

        @Override
        protected void animateAddImpl(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {

        }
    });
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    mAdapter = new SimpleCardViewAdapter(getActivity(),Arrays.asList(
            new CardViewData("BUNNY", "Description of Item 0", R.drawable.bunny),
            new CardViewData("Sample Title Item 1", "Description of Item 1", R.drawable.bunny_four),
            new CardViewData("Sample Title Item 2", "Description of Item 2", R.drawable.bunny_one),
            new CardViewData("Sample Title Item 3", "Description of Item 3", R.drawable.bunny_four),
            new CardViewData("Sample Title Item 4", "Description of Item 4", R.drawable.bunny_one)));

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    return  rootview;
}
```

}

SampleAdapter.class

```
public class SimpleCardViewAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleCardViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {



private int lastPosition = -1;
private Context context;
private List<CardViewData> mDataset;

public SimpleCardViewAdapter(Context context,List<CardViewData> dataset) {
    mDataset = dataset;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.primary_layout, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    final CardViewData cardViewData = mDataset.get(i);

    viewHolder.mTitle.setText(cardViewData.getTitle());
    viewHolder.mDescription.setText(cardViewData.getDescription());
    viewHolder.mImage.setImageResource(cardViewData.getImage());

    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
            (i > lastPosition) ? R.anim.up_from_bottom
                    : R.anim.down_from_top);
    viewHolder.itemView.startAnimation(animation);
    lastPosition = i;
    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Title: " + cardViewData.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset == null ? 0 : mDataset.size();

}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView mTitle;
    public TextView mDescription;
    public ImageView mImage;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_title);
        mDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_description);
        mImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_image);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: hi you want to add colour of your text view right.open your xml and paste the followind code and add colour as per your requirement.  android:textColor="#ff0000" you can take the clour from the xml also.file location: res/values/colors.xml The filename is arbitrary. The element's name will be used as the resource ID.android:textColor="@colors/text_color"

Comment: i need palette color,i want dynamically color pick from images@ManiTeja